# ZF3 Problem adding trusted proxies to session validator

Tags: zend-framework3

I am hosting a Zend Framework 3 site on MS Azure. There is a problem with the session validation as Azure's Application Gateway is acting as a reverse proxy which the remote address validator doesn't like so the session is not read.

I can see from the class reference for remote address that there is a method   `setTrustedProxies()`
which, according to the documenation, I can pass an array of IP addresses to. However I don't really have much of an idea of how to do this.

I am configuring the session_manager in global.php

```
'session_manager' => [
        // Session validators (used for security).
        'validators' => [
            RemoteAddr::class,
            HttpUserAgent::class,
        ],

    ],
```

Then, in Module.php I am instantiating the session manager using

```
$sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);
```

I am then trying to add the trusted proxies using the following with fake IPs

```
$sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);
$request        = $serviceManager->get('Request');
$remAdd = $request->getServer()->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
$remoteAddr = new RemoteAdddress($remAdd);
$remoteAddr->setTrustedProxies(['192.98.98.11', '187.2.2.10']);
$remoteAddr->setProxyHeader('X-Forwarded-For');
$remoteAddr->setUseProxy($useProxy = true);
$chain   = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain();
$chain->attach('session.validate', array($remoteAddr, 'isValid'));
```

I am almost certain this is not the correct way to do this but I can't find any documentation online about setting the trusted proxies.

If I do

```
$chain   = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain();
print_r($chain);
```

after adding the proxies I don't see any reference to proxies in the output

```
Zend\Session\ValidatorChain Object
(
    [events:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
            [session.validate] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [1] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] =&gt; 127.0.0.1
                                                )

                                            [1] =&gt; isValid
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [eventPrototype:protected] =&gt; Zend\EventManager\Event Object
        (
            [name:protected] =&gt; 
            [target:protected] =&gt; 
            [params:protected] =&gt; Array
                (
                )

            [stopPropagation:protected] =&gt; 
        )

    [identifiers:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [sharedManager:protected] =&gt; 
    [storage:protected] =&gt; Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage Object
        (
        )

)
```

As I said, I am pretty sure that I am going about this the wrong way so would be very grateful for any help in finding the correct method.

Comment: Have you tried: `$remoteAddressValidator = $sessionManager->getValidators()->get(RemoteAddr::class)` and then adding the IP's? I think that they're not set because you're instantiating a new instance of the RemoteAddr validator, instead of updating the instance already registered.

Comment: (Also, if this is something that changes regularly, you might wish to create a module in your back-end to manage these IP's and create a Provider class which reads that Entity and provides the IP's dynamically to the RemoteAddr validator. That way you won't need to re-deploy your project if/when these IP's change)

Comment: Hi rkeet. I haven't tried what you are suggesting but definitely will. I suspected I was just creating a new instance instead of updating the existing one, but wasn't sure how to correct that. The back-end module is a good idea which I will also look at in the long term. Thank you for once again responding to one of my questions. Much appreciated.

Comment: All good. Once you've given it a shot, update the question and I'll have a glance. Or provide an answer of course ;)

Comment: Hi rkeet, 
I gave that a shot but it doesn't like the getValidators() method. This is from the logs: 
"Call to undefined method Zend\\Session\\SessionManager::getValidators() ". I can see that $sessionManager has a property for the validators and it is "protected" which would make me think there must be a method for retreiving them.

Comment: After a quick look at the class it's probably `getValidatorChain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have stumbled upon the exact same issue, only in my case I am using CF.

Your approach is wrong because you are using Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress and you are not replacing the already loaded validator Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr.

Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr is internally using Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress so you should not use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/master/src/Validator/RemoteAddr.php

Here is the working code, tested:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

    // The following line instantiates the SessionManager and automatically
    // makes the SessionManager the 'default' one to avoid passing the 
    // session manager as a dependency to other models.
    $sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);

    $remoteAddr = new \Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr();
    //$remoteAddr->setTrustedProxies([]);
    $remoteAddr->setProxyHeader('CF-Connecting-IP');
    $remoteAddr->setUseProxy(true);


        $current_chain = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain(\Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr::class);

        $current_chain->attach(
                'session.validate',
               [ new \Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent(), 'isValid' ]
        );

        $current_chain->attach(
                'session.validate',
                [ $remoteAddr, 'isValid' ] 
            );

        $sessionManager->start();

        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
    }
```

**Result:**

```
Zend\Session\ValidatorChain Object
(
    [events:protected] => Array
        (
            [session.validate] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
                                                )

                                            [1] => isValid
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr Object
                                                (
                                                    [data:protected] => MY_REAL_IP
                                                )

                                            [1] => isValid
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I also added **print_r($remoteAddress);** inside https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/master/src/Validator/RemoteAddr.php function and test with TrustedProxies:

```
/**
 * Returns client IP address.
 *
 * @return string IP address.
 */
protected function getIpAddress()
{
    $remoteAddress = new RemoteAddress();
    $remoteAddress->setUseProxy(static::$useProxy);
    $remoteAddress->setTrustedProxies(static::$trustedProxies);
    $remoteAddress->setProxyHeader(static::$proxyHeader);

    print_r($remoteAddress);

    return $remoteAddress->getIpAddress();
}
```

**Result:**

```
Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress Object
(
    [useProxy:protected] => 1
    [trustedProxies:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 192.98.98.11
            [1] => 187.2.2.10
        )

    [proxyHeader:protected] => HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP
)
```

The conclusion is that setTrustedProxies is working, you just cannot see it because https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/master/src/Validator/RemoteAddr.php does not return this for it to be visible since it just passes it to Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress.

You can of course overwrite the 'default' SessionManager exactly like your code:

```
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions($config);
$sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
```

But this is just optional.

Comment: Thank you Norbert. Nice solution.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)